# Nativescript playground vue.js show error message "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res.list.splice)"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[Link(My weather apps)](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=OXuFGj&v=35)

```js
export const WEATHER_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
export const WEATHER_APIKEY = "2b27b121d7923afe1e02876057a88c10"; // from OpenWeatherMap
export const CURRENT_WEATHER_PATH = "weather/";
export const WEATHER_FORECAST_PATH = "forecast/daily/";
export const WEATHER_ICONS = {
    day: {
        clear: 0xf00d,
        clouds: 0xf002,
        drizzle: 0xf009,
        rain: 0xf008,
        thunderstorm: 0xf010,
        snow: 0xf00a,
        mist: 0xf0b6
    },
    night: {
        clear: 0xf02e,
        clouds: 0xf086,
        drizzle: 0xf029,
        rain: 0xf028,
        thunderstorm: 0xf02d,
        snow: 0xf02a,
        mist: 0xf04a
    },
    neutral: {
        temperature: 0xf055,
        wind: 0xf050,
        cloud: 0xf041,
        pressure: 0xf079,
        humidity: 0xf07a,
        rain: 0xf019,
        sunrise: 0xf051,
        sunset: 0xf052
    }
};
export const WIND_DIRECTIONS = [
    "North",
    "North-northeast",
    "Northeast",
    "East-northeast",
    "East",
    "East-southeast",
    "Southeast",
    "South-southeast",
    "South",
    "South-southwest",
    "Southwest",
    "West-southwest",
    "West",
    "West-northwest",
    "Northwest",
    "North-northwest"
];
```

I am a beginner in nativescript(vue.js), I am trying to design mobile phone apps that provide weather information to users. When I test the apps, it shows me an error message "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res.list.splice')" Could someone help me solve this error? Here is my code:

```js
<template>
    <Page class="page" @loaded="getForecast" :class="background_class">
        <ActionBar title="15-hours Forecast" class="action-bar">
            <NavigationButton android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"
                @tap="goToMainPage" />
        </ActionBar>
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="100%" height="100%">
            <ListView for="weather in forecastWeather" height="90%"
                :class="background_class">
                <v-template>
                    <GridLayout class="item" columns="*,*" rows="auto">
                        <StackLayout class="day-weather" row="0" col="0">
                            <Label :text="weather.day" class="date" />
                            <Label :text="weather.icon" class="icon" />
                            <Label :text="weather.description"
                                textWrap="true" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout class="details" row="0" col="1">
                            <GridLayout columns="auto,auto" rows="auto"
                                row="0" col="0">
                                <Label :text="weather.temperature.temp_max"
                                    class="temp day-temp" row="0" col="0" />
                                <Label :text="weather.temperature.temp_min"
                                    class="temp night-temp" row="0" col="1" />
                            </GridLayout>
                            <Label :text="weather.wind" />
                            <Label :text="weather.clouds" />
                            <Label :text="weather.pressure" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </GridLayout>
                </v-template>
            </ListView>
            <Label :text="msg" textWrap="true" />
        </StackLayout>

    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    import Forecast from "./ForecastWeather";

    const appSettings = require("tns-core-modules/application-settings");
    const requestor = require("./common/Requestor");
    const moment = require("~/moment");
    const constants = require("./common/Constants");
    const utilities = require("./common/Utilities");

    export default {
        methods: {
            goToMainPage() {
                this.$navigateBack();
            },
            getForecast() {
                this.background_class = utilities.getTimeOfDay();
                var url =
                    constants.WEATHER_URL +
                    constants.WEATHER_FORECAST_PATH +
                    "?lat=" +
                    this.currentGeoLocation.latitude +
                    "&lon=" +
                    this.currentGeoLocation.longitude +
                    "&apikey=" +
                    constants.WEATHER_APIKEY;
                requestor
                    .get(url)
                    .then(res => {
                        var forecast = [];
                        this.msg = "Retriving data...";
                        var list = res.list.splice(0, 5);
                        list.forEach(item => {
                            this.forecastWeather.push({
                                day: moment.unix(item.dt)
                                    .format("HH:00"),
                                icon: constants
                                    .WEATHER_ICONS["day"][
                                        item.weather[0]
                                        .main
                                        .toLowerCase()
                                    ],
                                temperature: {
                                    temp_max: utilities
                                        .convertKelvinToCelsius(
                                            item.main
                                            .temp_max)
                                        .toFixed(2),
                                    temp_min: utilities
                                        .convertKelvinToCelsius(
                                            item.main
                                            .temp_min)
                                        .toFixed(2)
                                },
                                wind: item.wind.speed +
                                    " m/s",
                                clouds: item.clouds.all +
                                    " %",
                                pressure: item.main
                                    .pressure + " hpa",
                                description: item.weather[
                                    0].description
                            });
                        });
                        this.forecastWeather = this.forecastWeather
                            .splice(0, 5);
                        this.msg = "Ready";
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.msg = error + " (Error: 201)";
                    });
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                currentGeoLocation: {
                    latitude: null,
                    longitude: null
                },
                msg: "",
                forecastWeather: [],
                background_class: ".day"
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.currentGeoLocation.latitude = appSettings.getNumber("clat");
            this.currentGeoLocation.longitude = appSettings.getNumber("clon");
            this.temp =
                this.currentGeoLocation.latitude +
                ", " +
                this.currentGeoLocation.longitude;
            this.getForecast();
        }
    };
</script>

<style>
    Page {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .item {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }

    .day-weather {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .details {
        horizontal-align:
            left;
    }

    .date {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .icon {
        font-size: 30px;

    }

    .temp {
        padding: 3px;
        text-align:
            center;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .day-temp {
        background-color: #d0c110;
    }

    .night-temp {
        background-color: #505050;
        color: #FFF;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Like the error says `res.list` is `undefined`, so calling `.splice()` on it will throw the mentioned error. Could you `console.log(res)` to check if it matches your expectations of the data?

Comment: I paste the link here. Could you help me to take a look?

Comment: [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=OXuFGj&v=34)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you changed the API key the response when requesting the forecast is:

```json
{
  "cod": 401,
  "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."
}
```

Solution: You might have to enable your API key for each endpoint separately, because it does work for when requesting the current weather.

**IMPORTANT:** With the posted code block/linked code you exposed your API key. Make sure you reset/regenerate it and the current API key does no longer work.

---

The important thing to note is that [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) within you `Requestor` does not check if the response is ok.

> ```js
> export function get(url) {
>     return fetch(
>         url
>     ).then(function (response) {
>         return response.json();
>     }).then(function (json) {
>         return json;
>     });
> }
> ```

The `fetch()` documentation says:

> The Promise returned from `fetch()` **won’t reject on HTTP error status** even if the response is an HTTP `404` or `500`. Instead, it will resolve normally (with `ok` status set to `false`), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

This means like `Requestor` is currently written you should check the `data.cod` for a success response (`200`). Alternatively you could rewrite your `Requestor` to throw on a not-ok response.

```js
// Return parsed JSON if response is ok. When the response is not ok
// reject with the response as error object.
export function get(url) {
  return fetch(url).then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) throw response;
    return response.json();
  });
}
```

Comment: How can I enable my API key for each endpoint separately?